# ajax not properly parsing the value returned by php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem with my ajax code. Its supposed to check a returned value from php, but it's always returning undefined or some other irrelevant value. As i'm quite new to ajax methodologies i can't seem to find a headway around this. I've searched numerous link on stackoverflow and other relevant forums regarding the solution but none helped. The problem remains the same

Here is the ajax code::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
    var path = $('#path').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'frontEnd.php',
        data: {path: path },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data) {

            if (data == 1) {
                 alert("Value entered successfully" + data);
           } else if (data == 0) {
                 alert("Sorry an error has occured" + data);
        }

    });

    return false;
})
});
```

The problem lies with outputting the value of data. The php code returns 1 if the value is successfully entered in the database and 0 otherwise. And the ajax snippet is supposed to check the return value and print the appropriate message. But its not doing such.

Here is the php code::

```
<?php
 require './fileAdd.php';    
$dir_path = $_POST['path'];    
$insVal = new fileAdd($dir_path);
$ret = $insVal->parseDir();
if ($ret ==1 ) {
      echo '1';
   } else {
     echo '0';
    }      
?>
```

I can't find a way to solve it. Please help;

Comment: may be the `dataType` on your ajax settings?

Comment: why set datatype to json, your server doesn't return json here

Comment: oh i thought that returning any data from the server except ints have to be parsed as json. Clearly i was wrong. anyways thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
    var path = $('#path').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'frontEnd.php',
        data: {path: path },
        type: 'POST',
        //dataType: 'json', Just comment it out and you will see your data
```

OR

```
dataType: 'text',
```

Answer (score 1):

Because closing `}` brackets not matching try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-button').click(function() {
        var path = $('#path').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'frontEnd.php',
            data: {path: path},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text', //<-- the server is returning text, not json
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    alert("Value entered successfully" + data);
                } else if (data == 0) {
                    alert("Sorry an error has occured" + data);
                }
            } //<-- you forgot to close the 'success' function
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: nitpik: it might be helpful to show what you changed. That's a tough one to catch. +1

Comment: In OP code there is unwanted `);` after `success: function(data) {` closing `}` and `$(document).ready(function() {` closing brackets `});` are missing. I have also removed unwanted `return false;` code

Comment: Don't you still need to return `false` from the click handler?

Comment: Yes its required to prevent form submission. Thanks for correcting me, I have updated the code.

Comment: I added comments to your code just to show where the changes are. Feel free to edit it further if I missed anything.

Comment: yep that fixed the issue. And the missing braces might be some typo that occured when i was poting the question. Thanks a lot for the correction, really helped